Compose. Scrolling a list with hiding SearchBar
Good day. The task is to put a SearchBar at the top of the list so that when scrolling the list the search is hidden. The behavior is somewhat similar to topappbar. Attempts to install search in the appbar were unsuccessful. In the end, I realized that nestedscrollconnection seems to be involved here, but things didn’t go further than this understanding. On the mp3 website I found a video of exactly the behavior that I would like to implement.
Scroll to the "Scroll" category
https://m3.material.io/components/search/guidelines
I tried to combine topapbar and searchbar but the behavior is not what I need.

Then, let's see the code! Please [edit] your question and add thse parts of the code that you have problems with.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
